# Magento C.E 1.9.1.1 Missing Mage_XmlConnect table

Tags: magento-1.9, module, ce-1.9.1.1, mage-xmlconnect

I have just install magento C.E latest version: 1.9.1.1

And after `install completed`, i have checked the database and find that `all table for Mage_XmlConnect modules are missing`.But i have check it exit till `magento C.E 1.9.0.1`.

**Missing Table Are:**

- xmlconnect_application
- xmlconnect_config_data
- xmlconnect_history
- xmlconnect_images
- xmlconnect_notification_template
- xmlconnect_queue

**Can any one tell me.is this bug or feature on magento C.E 1.9.1.1**

Comment: good question. +1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at a `Mage_XmlConnect.xml` from `app>etc`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_XmlConnect>
            <active>false</active>  <----- look at a this
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
                <Mage_Paypal />
                <Mage_Usa />
                <Mage_Tax />
                <Mage_Weee />
                <Mage_Catalog />
                <Mage_CatalogSearch />
                <Mage_CatalogInventory />
                <Mage_Bundle />
                <Mage_Wishlist />
                <Mage_Rating />
                <Mage_Review />
            </depends>
        </Mage_XmlConnect>
    </modules>
</config>
```

By default it is `disabled` mode.If you `enabled` this then it will create table.

**As per magento changelog list**

Magento Resolved a potential [XML External Entity Processing (XXE)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing) exploit that might lead to a Denial of Service attack.

Magento Mobile uses the XmlConnect module to provide mobile phone storefront.Because `XmlConnect` is disabled by default, users who try to view your mobile storefront might see the error, “`The server responded with invalid data`.”

For more info [Click Here](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.1.html%3FTocPath%3DAppendices%7C_____1)

Comment: glad to help you @AmitBera

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Keyur answer, as of Magento Community Edition 1.9.1.0 the default behaviour for `Mage_XmlConnect` is for it to be `disabled` mode.